# Unable to Retrieve ListBox Item Value ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

My `ListFolder` listbox control is returning 0 item.

I have put in a `testLB` listbox control for testing and items can be retrieved.

Below are the code snippets.

**Frontend:**

```
//Returned 0
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="sectionC" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="listFolder" CssClass="fileHeight" Style="width: 100%;" SelectionMode="Single" ClientIDMode="Static" onclick="onListFolderClick(); ">
        </asp:ListBox>
    </div>
</div>

//Returned 1
<asp:ListBox ID="testLB" class="chosen" runat="server" Width="450px" Height="20px" SelectionMode="Single" ClientIDMode="Static">
    <asp:ListItem>item1</asp:ListItem>  
</asp:ListBox>
```

**On Page Load:**

```
//Returned 0
Log.LogDebug("listFolder.Items.Count:" + listFolder.Items.Count, Location);

//Returned 1 
Log.LogDebug("testLB.Items.Count: " + testLB.Items.Count, Location);
```

**Page UI Screenshot:**

[image]

Headers are selected on the left control `All Headers`, and added/removed individually to the right control `Selected Headers`, `listFolders` lb control.

Lastly, `Generate Report` button is clicked and all values in `listFolder` lb control are to be retrieved.

Do I need to include a container to store the items e.g. `<asp:ListItem>` to be able to retrieve lb values?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fitst you have to change `SelectionMode` to `Multiple`

```
<asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="listFolder" CssClass="fileHeight" Style="width: 100%;" SelectionMode="Multiple" ClientIDMode="Static" onclick="onListFolderClick(); ">
        </asp:ListBox>
```

Create javascript method to select all item in `listFolder`:

```
function SelectAllItems() {
    $("#listFolder").each(function() { 
        $("#listFolder option").attr("selected", "selected"); 
    }); 

    $("#listFolder").focus();
}
```

Call `SelectAllItems` on Generate Report button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Generate Report" onsubmit="SelectAllItems()" />
```